# how do i get a tooltip such as cluetip, to work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, cluetip

My cluetip works great in Chrome, but whenever I bring the same exact code to IE it doesn't even show up or it shows the default tooltip. Any suggestions? Is there some code I can put in my cluetip to make it work in IE? Any help would be appreciated.

Is there some code needed to make cluetip or other customer tooltips work in IE??

Answer (score 0):

Try my tooltip plugin for jQuery. It is optimized for the use with mobile phones and works with IE lt 7: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.tooltip.js

That is not an answer but an alternative to cluetip.

Comment: Ok i will check it out! Do you have a demo page?